# Vertical align 3 "panel panel-default" so they are all the same height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row and in that row I have 3 parts which all are using the same code to generate but I can not keep them the same height.  I am using HTML 5 and also using Bootstrap 3.  on the "panel panel-default" I have tried using a "min-height" but when I add link to one of the sections, it only expands that section.

It's a little hard for me to explain.

my view is:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 540px">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><%=title %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal"><%=template.ToString() %></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which makes the page look like:

[image: Which makes the page look like:]

Now as each column is using the same code how can I keep each one in-line so if a new link was added/removed to one the first. each panel border runs inline.

At the present I have a `min-height` set but the screenshot below shows this doesn't work when a new link is added.

I would like to do it without the use of CSS or Java/JQuery.

Comment: looks to me like this is doing what it is supposed to, sets all 3 columns to 540 minimum, but when a column is longer than that "minimum", it expands.  There is no way for the other columns to know that they should be longer, other than through JavaScript / JQuery dynamically updating their parameters.

Comment: your image is not visible for me,  and pls let me know the clear requirement

Comment: where you are adding and removing the link, pls post fiddle

Comment: Andy > If I need to use JavaScript / JQuery, how do I go about it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this..

http://www.bootply.com/iH9uUHI4Zs

```
.flex, .flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

It uses CSS flexbox to make the height of the columns in a row the height of the tallest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this doesn't work at all as all my coloumn's are touching and display everything on one line which isn't as I want.  I need each panel to be displayed as my screenshot.